# link_to with the remote true not working in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= link_to_remote "See more", :url => { :action => "aajax_activity", :page_current => (@page_current.to_i + 1), :user_id=>@sampleuser_profile.id }, :update => "sbottom_activity_#{@page_current.to_s}", :position => :before %>
```

while converting this link_to_remote  to link_to in rails 3 not working

```
<%= link_to  "See more" , :url => { :action => "aajax_activity", :page_current => (@page_current.to_i + 1), :user_id=>@sampleuser_profile.id }, :update => "sbottom_activity_#{@page_current.to_s}", :position => :before ,:remote=>true %>
```

any idea ?

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get any errors etc.?

Answer (score 2):

The reason seems to be a missing jQuery Library. In Rails 3 this can occur if `jquery_ujs.js` (the unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery) is missing. Add it to the default Javascript files in `config/application.rb`, for example by

```
  config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery jquery_ujs)
```

or in your layout.rb

```
javascript_include_tag :defaults, "jquery_ujs.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

me too having same issue. I updated the rails.js file and now its working perfectly.
http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

Answer (score 0):

The following link should work

```
<%= link_to  "See more" , :url => { :action => "aajax_activity", :user_id=>@sampleuser_profile.id },:remote=>true, :method => :post %>
```

To update the data you have to write the javascript code in the file **aajax_activity.js.erb**